# Don't we abuse notation when we say Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space and $X$ a r.v.

Tags: probability

I often see in books and exercise: Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space. Let $X$ and $Y$ independent random variable s.t. $X$ is normal and $Y$ is exponentially distributed.

**Question** Don't we abuse notation when we say that ? A priori, it's not clear that there are two r.v. $X\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$ and $Y\sim \exp(1)$ that are independent.

---

I know anyway that we can construct a probability space $(\Omega ',\mathcal F',\mathbb P')$ s.t. there is two independent r.v. $X$ and $Y$ s.t. $X$ is normal and $Y$ is exponential. But rigorously speaking, to fix a probability space and then take to independent r.v. is not correct, right ?

Comment: This is just like: Let set $S$ be given. Let $f:S \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined....then... (goes theorem statement). Adding "Such that" before the second sentence may ease your doubt.

Comment: But in what you wrote, such a function $f$ could not exist.

Comment: Why? $f$ need not be onto. Anyway, in your case the sentence following the claim of probability space should add "such that", to put precisely.

Answer (score 2):

Given any family of distribution functions $(F_i)$ there is a probability space on which there are independent random variables $(X_i)$ such that $X_i$ has distribution $F_i$ for each $i$. I don't see any abuse of notation here. In fact it is very important that whenever we study independent random variables we assume that they are defined on the same probability space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see what you mean, but it's just the fact that instead of writing : Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space. Let $X,Y$ r.v. on $\Omega $. It would be better to write : Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space s.t. there are $X$ and $Y$ independent s.t. $X$ have distribution $F_1$ and $Y$ has distribution $F_2$. Don't you think so ?

Comment: Also, when you say "there is a single probability space", does you mean that this probability space is unique ? If yes, it's quitte surprising...

Comment: No, I didn 't mean to talk about any uniqueness. There always infinitely many probability spaces for a given family $(F_i)$.

Answer (score 2):

There are such spaces; for instance $\Omega=\{0,1\}$ cannot "support" any continuous random variable (not to mention two indipendent ones). That being said, I wouldn't say we are abusing the notation more than we are (and we aren't) when we say:

> Let $V$ be a vector space and let $W$ be a vector subspace such that $\dim W\ge 2$...

It's just a theorem with two/three hypothesis, which will happen to be vacuously true if one of them is not met.

Answer (score 1):

No!  There are no abuse of notation here.  The only implicit point is that $\Omega$ needs to be large enough to accommodate two independent random variables, an assumption which was not stated at the beginning.  What would really be abusing notation is if we start with letting $X,Y$ be random variables not necessarily on the same probability space and go back to construct a probability space on which we have independent copies that is still denoted $X,Y$.

Answer (score 0):

For me, there is no abuse of notion. For example, you can say

> $(P1)$ Let $A\subset \mathbb N$. Let $n\in A$ s.t. $2\mid n$.

This is perfectly correct ! Indeed, such a $n$ may not exist, and so, there is no reason to consider it. But as far as you don't claim that such a $n$ exist, your proposition is completely correct. However, this is not correct :

> $(P2)$ Let $A\subset \mathbb N$. There exist $n\in A$ s.t. $2\mid n$.

as far as you didn't suppose that $A\cap 2\mathbb N\neq \emptyset$.